# AWS API Gateway - Call GET Method with C# SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk

I have an API Gateway that uses IAM authorization.  I have a C# application that I'm hoping to call the API with.  I started with a `GetMethodRequest` but I don't see anyway to set the PathPart parameter.

```
var userId = _remoteCredentials.UserId;
var key = _remoteCredentials.Key;

var client = new AmazonAPIGatewayClient(userId, key, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
GetMethodRequest getMethodRequest = new GetMethodRequest();
getMethodRequest.HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Get.ToString();
getMethodRequest.ResourceId = "4abcde";
getMethodRequest.RestApiId = "aasfasdfs";

var task = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetMethodAsync(getMethodRequest).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

I was expecting something like the `Test-AGInvokeMethod` in the Powershell SDK which allows me to set the query string and the path.

```
$response = Test-AGInvokeMethod 
                   -RestApiId aasfasdfs
                   -ResourceId 4abcde
                   -HttpMethod GET 
                   -PathWithQueryString '/etl/upload_url'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** Below is something of a solution that I ended up using the `AWS4RequestSigner` is a library that I found on Github

```
var signer = new AWS4RequestSigner(userId, key);
var destinationUrl = string.Format("https://ad9vxabc123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/etl/summary/latest?tms_id={0}&model_id={1}", _tmsId, _modelId);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri(destinationUrl),
};

var signed = Task.Run(async () => await signer.Sign(request, "execute-api", "us-east-2").ConfigureAwait(false));
var signedResult = signed.Result;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`AmazonAPIGatewayClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/APIGateway/TAPIGatewayClient.html) is for *managing* your API Gateway e.g. adding new stages or deleting API keys.

You're looking to *invoke* a method on your API Gateway, like [`Test-AGInvokeMethod`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Test-AGInvokeMethod.html) does.

To invoke your API gateway, you need to call the [deployed API endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html) using a HTTP client.

.NET's in-built [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) is a good start.